# How to pass HANDLEs between C#.NET and C Win32 DLL?

Tags: c#, c, winapi, handle

I have a C#.NET application and an unmanaged C Win32 .DLL program.
How can i pass HANDLEs between the two app? 
i mean i wanna set a HANDLE from C code to a output parameter that comes from C#, and again, pass the HANDLE from C# to another function in the DLL?
I guess it is related to IntPtr, but i don't know what the C & C# code should be!

thanks.

Comment: What are you talking about? HANDLEs or HANDLERs? And what is a HANDLER?

Comment: Sorry. i corrected mistakes. i meant HANDLE that is 'void *' in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call C code from C#, you can use the DllImportAttribute to indicate the parameter as IntPtr:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", EntryPoint="my_c_function")]
public static extern void my_c_function(IntPtr myHandle);

[DllImport("mydll.dll", EntryPoint="my_c_function_with_out_param")]
public static extern void my_c_function(out IntPtr returnedHandle);
```

Just make sure that your C functions look like this:

```
void my_c_function(HANDLE myHandle) 
{   
    // ....
}

void my_c_function_with_out_param(HANDLE * pReturnedHandle)
{
   // ....
   *pReturnedHandle = GenerateHandle();    
}
```

Comment: very good help. thank you for your help and the time u spent.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast it ti IntPtr type in C code.

Answer (score 0):

`HANDLE` is defined as `void*`, i.e. something the size of a pointer.  The equivalent in the managed world is `IntPtr`.